# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}[(x-1/2)^{2}-x^{4}\ln^2{(1+1/x)}]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm working on real analysis and struggled with the problem for days.
It seems to me that I should factor the formula into $[(x-1/2)-x^2\ln{(1+1/x)}][(x-1/2)+x^2\ln{(1+1/x)}]$ and try a way out though $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{1+1/x}}{1/x}=1$. But I failed.
Would you help me find it out? I'd appreciate your help. Best regards.

Comment: Try a Taylor expansion for the logarithm.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you so much! I will have a try.

Comment: @MyGlasses unfortunately it's $(x-1/2)^2$. If it's $(x+1/2)$, is there a way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln(1+t)=t-\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{t^3}{3}-\dfrac{t^4}{4}+\cdots$

$\ln^2(1+t)=\left(t-\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{t^3}{3}-\dfrac{t^4}{4}+\cdots\right)^2=t^2-t^3+\dfrac{11}{12}t^4+O(t^5)$

$x^4\ln^2(1+\dfrac1x)=x^2-x+\dfrac{11}{12}+O(\dfrac1x)$

$(x-\dfrac12)^2-x^4\ln^2(1+\dfrac1x)=-\dfrac{2}{3}+O(\dfrac1x)$

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't thought that Taylor expansion is such powerful in slove this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put   $y=\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x}}$, then $y\to 0^{+}$  because $x\to\infty$. So

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-x^{4}\ln^{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{\ln^{2}\left(1+y\right)}{y^4}\right)
=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{y^{2}(2-y)^{2}-4\ln^{2}(1+y)}{4y^{4}}\right).$$

Then applying L'hôpital's rule **2 times** you can get rid of the squared logarithm in the expression and then will get $-\frac{2}{3}$. In effect,

$\displaystyle{\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{y^{4}-4y^{3}+4y^{2}-4\ln^{2}(1+y)}{4y^{4}} } 
\overset{L.H.}{=}\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\displaystyle{\frac{4y^{3}-12y^{2}+8y-8\ln(1+y)\displaystyle{\frac{1}{1+y}}}{16y^{3}}}
=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{(1+y)(4y^{3}-12y^{2}+8y)-8\ln(1+y)}{16y^{3}(1+y)}
=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{(4y^{3}-12y^{2}+8y)+(4y^{4}-12y^{3}+8y^{2})-8\ln(1+y)}{16y^{4}+16y^{3}}
=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{4y^{4}-8y^{3}-4y^{2}+8y-8\ln(1+y)}{16y^{4}+16y^{3}}
\overset{L.H.}{=}\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{16y^{3}-24y^{2}-8y+8-\displaystyle{\frac{8}{1+y}}}{64y^{3}+48y^{2}}
=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{(6y^{3}-24y^{2}-8y+8)(1+y)-8}{(64y^{3}+48y^{2})(1+y)}\overset{L.H.}{=} \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{6y^{4}-18y^{3}-32y^{2}}{64y^{4}+112y^{3}+48y^{2}}= \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\frac{6y^{2}-18y-32}{64y^{2}+112y+48}=\frac{-32}{48}=\frac{-2}{3}$

This can be donne also in similar cases like:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\frac{x}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\right)=\frac{1}{e}\cdot\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{e-(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}}{y}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Where $e$ is the Euler's number.

The limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{e-(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}}{y}\right)}$ is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and by L.H. rule:

$$ \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{e-(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}}{y}\right)=\frac{e}{2}. $$

As before you can do the same change of variables $y=\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x}}$ and apply L'hôpital's rule to verify the answer. Clearly the most difficult thing is to compute well the derivative of $(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}$ w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: This is bit complicated and repeated application of L'Hospital's Rule is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! L'hôpital's rule is really another quite powerful tool in calculating limit. It seems that exchange the variable to its reciprocal and make the formula into a form of P(x)/Q(x) always inspries one to find a way out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put $x=1/t$ so that $t\to 0^{+}$. And the limit gets transformed into $$\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{t^{2}(t-2)^{2}-4(\log(1+t))^{2}}{4t^{4}}$$ The numerator can now be factorized and we can write the above as $$\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{t^{2} -2t - 2\log(1+t)}{4t}\cdot\frac{t^{2}-2t+2\log(1+t)}{t^{3}}$$ The first fraction above tends to $(0-2-2)/4=-1$ and hence the limit is equal to $$\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{2t-t^{2}-2\log(1+t)}{t^{3}}$$ and after this we can use Taylor expansions to get the answer $-2/3$. Proceeding in this manner avoids any manipulation of Taylor series and the result is arrived using a famous and easy to remember series for $\log(1+t)$. Often a little algebra before Taylor series expansions helps to simplify the use of these expansions.

It is also possible to evaluate the last limit above using L'Hospital's Rule. Using L'Hospital's Rule we get $$\frac{1}{3}\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{2-2t-\dfrac{2}{1+t}}{t^{2}}=\frac{2}{3}\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{-1}{1+t}=-\frac{2}{3}$$ and thus just a single application of L'Hospital's Rule is all we need to evaluate the limit. Like in case of Taylor expansions, it is always better to apply a little bit of algebra to simplify the expression before applying L'Hospital's Rule and one should avoid its repeated application.

---

While the factorization  of numerator in the initial step is obvious it is not at all clear why the denominator is split as $t\cdot t^{3}$ instead of the more natural $t^{2}\cdot t^{2}$. Well, before posting this answer I did factorize the denominator as $t^{2}\cdot t^{2}$, but then the first fraction diverged and second one was converging to $0$. When a limit is split as a product of two limits it is desirable to have one of the limits as non-zero and finite so that that particular limit is evaluated and the focus shifts on the evaluation of the other limit. It was easy to observe that the first factor would give a non-zero limit if the denominator is split as $t\cdot t^{3}$ and then I posted the same here.

Comment: Your answer is really elegent! Although using Taylor expansions and L'Hospital's Rule directly is quite striaght forward, the factorization of denominator is quite charming. I really appreciate your kind detailed explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Alfred for kind words. The Taylor series approach in accepted answer is direct and simple and I don't think there is any problem there. But when one needs to compute Taylor series for $\sin\log(1+x)$ it becomes a bit challenging.